# Derivative with respect to a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators

I am coming across a derivative taken with respect to a functional and I am confused by its meaning. Say I have functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, say from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if the generalization is non-trivial I am also interested in the case $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and a  functional $F[f]$. Does it make sense to take a derivative with respect to $F[g]$? Would it equal

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F[g]} F[f] \stackrel{?}{=} \int dx \, \delta(f(x)-g(x))$$
If correct how do I see this? (I reasoned by consistency of the expression and analogy with the function case.)

When in general does it make sense to take a derivative with respect to a functional. What would we get if the expression we were taking a derivative of does not only depend on $F$. Is there still some meaningful value to be assigned? Take for example the cases

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F[g]} (f(x') F[f]) $$

and

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F[g]} \frac{\delta}{\delta f(x')} F[f]$$

and
$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F[g]} \int df \frac{\delta}{\delta f(x')} F[f]$$

In the latter two would it make sense to pass $\frac{\delta}{\delta F[f']}$ through the integral and the derivative and perform it first?

---

I think I should be comparing against $\frac{d f(x)}{d g(x)}$ which has meaning in terms of the chain rule, but I am a bit confused in how it would work for a functional.

(I am a theoretical physicist and not a mathematician.)

---

Edit: previously $g(x)$ read $f'(x)$ which was interpreted as a derivative of $f(x)$ in an answer. So that an answer describes a specific case of my more general question.

---

I think in this context $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary $\mathbb{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ functions and usually will all be integrated over eventually.

We usually assume $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(y)}=\delta(x-y) $. I guess I would also need to define $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta g(y)}$ but I don't know what it should be.

---

Perhaps it would be simpler to start with what would happen in a simple example. Say we take

$$ F[f] = \int df \, e^{-\int dx \, f(x)^2} $$

Comment: Oops, perhaps I should have used math.stackexchange? If so can I be migrated or should I delete and repost?

Comment: Migration puts more strain on the moderators. It is probably easier if you just copied your post and pasted it on MSE (it is also much faster than wait for the moderators to act, since they can be busy with other stuff).

Comment: @AlexM., ok I will do so. You think math would indeed be a better fit?

Comment: $F[f']$ is a different functional $G$ of $f$, so you want to make sense of $\delta F[f]/\delta G[f]$; to make sense of this you would need to specify what you are varying and what you keep constant; if only $f$ is varied, at constant $F,G$, I would know the answer; is that what you seek?

Comment: If you do repost there, you can flag this question for moderator attention, and ask for it to be closed/deleted.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: The OP can close or delete by himself, no need for moderator assistance.

Comment: @Kvothe: Yes, I'd say MSE would be a better fit, but this is just *my* opinion.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I think that is what I am looking for yes. But I am not sure I understand your comment. What would it mean for $F$ and $G$ to not be considered constant? I consider here F and G to be a function only of f. So of course F and G change if we change f, but there is no other parameter that could cause a change. Am I missing something?

Comment: suppose $F$ is a linear operator, $F[f]=M\cdot f$; when you vary $F[f]$ do you keep $M$ fixed or not?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, Yes I would keep $M$ fixed. It seems clear to me that if $F$ happens to be part of some family of functionals parameterized for example by $M$ that I did not mention than it should clearly be assumed that there is no movement within this unspecified family. Are you just being thorough (if so thank you btw) or am I still missing something, a reason why it would make more sense to consider also a change of $M$ or something?

Comment: @Kvothe --- I saw the edit with the specific example for the functional $F$, which is a good way to proceed, but then can you also tell us how $g$ and $f$ are related? We need to know that if we wish to compute $\delta F[f]/\delta F[g]$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, in a way that requirement is the answer to my question. I was hoping that without any relationship  between these functions except both being $\mathbb{L}^2$ an expression would follow. I guess the hope would be that this will be non-zero only if $f=g$ giving a delta function in function space.

The main object that I hope is well defined is $ \frac{\delta}{\delta F[g]} A[F]$ where $A[F]$ is some $f$ independent expression of the form $\int df \, h(F[f])$. Since we are integrating over $f$ and thus acting on any $f$ it will in general have no special relation to $g$.

Answer (score 1):

define the linearization of the functional $F$ by $F[f+\delta f]=F[f]+F_1\circ\delta f+{\cal O}(\delta f)^2$, where $F_1$ is a linear functional; denote the differential operator by $D$; then $\delta F[f']=F_1\circ D\circ\delta f$, $\delta F[f]=F_1\circ\delta f=F_1\circ D^{-1}\circ F_1^{-1}\circ\delta F\circ f'$,  and hence
$$\frac{\delta F[f]}{\delta F[f']}=F_1\circ D^{-1}\circ F_1^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I was unclear in the question. With $f'$ I simply meant a different function $g$. Not one related by differentiation. I don't think you used any property of the differential operator, except invertibility, so if  they are related by any invertible map I think the same result should still apply. But looking at the final result I am not sure how to think of this functional that first applies the inverse linearized functional. Is the result expressible in terms of something like my first equation?

That was completely bad notation on my part.

Comment: Oops the last sentence of my comment was not supposed to be there anymore but I cannot edit it. It refers to the $f'$ notation being bad for a different function $g$.

Comment: you will have to tell me how changes in $g$ are related to changes in $f$, otherwise I cannot make sense of the derivative; in your original question it seemed $g\equiv f'$ is the derivative of $f$, and then I know how $\delta g$ is related to $\delta f$, by a linear operator $D$, the inverse being integration.